# Current date is between two columns

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a following table tbldates.I want to return all rows in which current date is between start date and end date columns.

```
startdate   enddate
9/13/2013   11/13/2014
9/14/2013   11/12/2014
9/15/2013   12/12/2014
6/12/2012   8/12/2013
6/12/2012   8/12/2012

SELECT * FROM tbldates d WHERE    to_date(SYSDATE) BETWEEN d.startdate AND d.enddate
```

Above query is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is it showing any error?

Comment: I have a very big tables of dates.In which all dates are available

Comment: `startdate` and `enddate` are `date` type or `varchar2` type?

Comment: `to_date(sysdate)` is totally useless and error prone. `sysdate` **is** already a date. So that expression converts a date to a varchar and then back to a date. All that using implicit data type casts based on the current client's NLS settings. If you want to get rid of the time, use `trunc`. Which data type are the columns `startdate` and `enddate`

Answer (score 3):

You have to first convert your `VARCHAR` column into `DATE` using`TO_DATE()` with the format. And then `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` actually, removes the time element in current date.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbldates d 
WHERE    
TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE(d.startdate,'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(d.enddate,'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

If `startdate` and `enddate` are date already, this would work straight forward!

```
SELECT * 
    FROM tbldates d 
    WHERE    
    TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN d.startdate AND d.enddate
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75d4a/1)

Comment: +1 the only answer that correctly uses `to_date()` and `trunc()`

Comment: What is the datatype of those column .. is it Date?

Comment: @WaqasAli I added a Fiddle demo with this data and it works fine. Can you double check the data type?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 SELECT *  FROM table 
 WHERE TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN d.startdate AND d.enddate
```